# How to Get Tree Structure Levels in ASP.MVC 5?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

[image: Accounts]

How to design in mvc5 and bootstrap??

Comment: what is your question exactly? regarding how to design using bootstrap - fetch data in any html format, style using css. But I don't think you're asking this.

Comment: I tried to state the account in index page look like above image. its same as tree structure

Comment: It's just some ul li that you can style that, Important part is using recursive function for generating it.

Comment: thnx. i get an answer for that.